# storyboardWithName:bundle: is allocating memory for stoyboard object?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, uistoryboard, allocation

Let's say

```
NSNumber *number =[[NSNumber alloc] numberWithInetger]
```

**Edit above line should be:**

```
NSNumber *number =[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:0]
```

This is allocating memory for variable

However this is not:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]
```

Now in my case I want to investigate what happens behind this line:

```
 _storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

1. By repeating (`storyboardWithName`) method in a loop I allocate different memory each time?If my storyboard is huge, is it bad practice?
2. If I use this method (`storyboardWithName`) inside one method block, is it better to define it inside only that method? After completing method block it will release automatically? What if defined as class member variable?
3. If I allocate this object, when dose it get de-allocated by memory management (`@autoreleasepool`)?*

Basically what dose this mean in my case:

> And for this method says:
>
> - storyboardWithName:bundle:
>
> Creates and returns a storyboard object for the specified storyboard
>   resource file.

.....

> **Return Value** A storyboard object for the specified file. If no
>   storyboard resource file matching name exists, an exception is thrown
>   with description: Could not find a storyboard named 'XXXXXX' in
>   bundle....
>
> Discussion Use this method to retrieve the storyboard object
>   containing the view controller graph you want to access. All of the
>   resources associated with the storyboard must be in the bundle
>   indicated by the storyboardBundleOrNil parameter.
>
> is retaining object but since we did not alloc/copy there won't be
>   need to release the variable.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010909-CH1-SW6

**UPDATE**

This is what I understand from this slide, I am a bit confuse!

[image]

Link to slide: http://www.slideshare.net/whalec1/ios-memory-management-basis

Comment: NSNumber *number has been allocated memory.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) Your first line of code shouldn't compile because `alloc` creates an instance, but `numberWithInteger` is a class method.  2) `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]` documentation says it creates an object, which suggests allocating memory.  (There's a possibility that there's sharing or caching going on, but from the caller's perspective it needs to be treated as if it were allocating memory.)

Comment: @PhillipMills Please see edited line of code

Comment: This updated code: `NSNumber *number =[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger]` is still wrong. It should read `NSNumber *number =[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: 1]`. You must add a colon and provide an integer

Answer (score 1):

Creating lots of storyboards objects is not a bad practice, until you really need them.

Also, It might not be as huge as you expect it. When storyboard is instantiated, its just the story board that has been instantiated, none of the scenes will be allocated memory until you do so using 
`- (__kindof UIViewController *)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;`

A ViewController that has been instantiated using the above method, has property 
`@property(nullable, nonatomic, readonly, strong) UIStoryboard *storyboard`, that stores a strong reference to the storyboard. So even if the local storyboard object goes out of scope, the storyboard object is strongly referenced by the controller and does not release until ViewControllers get released.

Comment: Thank's for answer. I think you understand the point of question. Just can you explain if in a block of code  I reapeat two times

 `A = instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`
 `B = instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

 Am I allocating different chunk of memory to each line. By the way identifier and storyboard is same each time

Comment: @Bernard Yes! Every call to instantiateViewContrller allocates memory to a viewcontroller object, even if storyboard and id are same.

Comment: Can you add a bit about de-allocating. is it better to define a storyboard as a class member and use it every places I need it, OR I instantiate in each block I need it and hopping memory management will release it. Which one is more expensive for performance and better way to practice this?

Comment: @Bernard i would suggest you to make a class member. It is better practice and by this we can avoid unwanted memory allocations

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question is wrong.

You say

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]
```

Does not allocate memory. Of course it does.

That method is a "convenience method". It is a class method that internally allocates and initializes an object.

`NSNumber` is a special case however. Internally, the system does some special handling of commonly used number values. If you create more than one instance of `numberWithInteger:1`, for example, you will get pointers to the same object rather than multiple unique objects that hold the same value.

As to storyboards, a storyboard is a big complex object that contains other objects, does file management, etc. When you create a storyboard with `storyboardWithName` the system does not load all the view controllers inside the storyboard. It creates the top-level object, which then creates view controllers as needed.

If you call `storyboardWithName` repeatedly inside a loop then yes, it will create a new object each time. Don't do that. You should create a storyboard object once for each name in the lifetime of your application and then use that single instance of the storyboard throughout.

Comment: So in the lifetime of your application, do you mean I need to create singleton refer to main storyboard? I only have one main storyboard by the way. I use some places` instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and before that I use `UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`

Answer (score 1):

`NSNumber *number =[[NSNumber alloc] numberWithInetger]`, this is not possible. It is wrong syntax.

`NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]` definitely alloc the memory.

`_storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];` means `_storyboard` is reference for your `Storyboard` so, it's just points the storyboard or memory that allocated by storyboard. It's not create another copy of storyboard.

Comment: Still this is wrong. If you want to use `initWithInteger` then you should pass integer parameter something like : `NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInteger:1];` And it will alloc memory and `NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1]` also alloc memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just need a bit more explaination. If I say two times:

`UIStoryboard _storyboard1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIStoryboard _storyboard2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];`

Am I allocating two chunks of memory?

Comment: Actually, the docs suggest that storyboardWithName **does** allocate a new storyboard object. They say "Creates and returns a storyboard object for the specified storyboard resource file." It is unclear, though, because later the docs say "Use this method to *retrieve* the storyboard object containing the view controller graph you want to access."

Comment: Yead @DuncanC is right. It is confusing but i think it not create another object it's just point the storyboard object. So, if you create multiple instance then it not alloc storyboard that much time but it make pointer to that much time, means create reference that much time, so it is better to use single instance where possible.

Comment: I practically test this and put breakpoint on each line. There was two variable with different memory address. I am not sure if this is address for variable itself and they point to same memory address or I have two instances!